# Audit mailbox actions on Exchange

Tags: exchange-2007, mailbox, contacts

Is there a way to audit each action performed in an Exchange 2007 mailbox? In this particular case, a user, on many occasions, has complained that items from his contacts have dissapeared. I would like to be able to check an audit log when this happens, so I can tell him definitively what happened; whether he accidentally deleted it, dragged and dropped it, or if someone who has access to his contacts did.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you're going to be disappointed.

Mailbox audit logging sounds exactly like what you're looking for, but it is an [Exchange 2010 and newer feature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff459237(v=exchg.141).aspx). Exchange 2007 had [mailbox access auditing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee221156(v=EXCHG.80).aspx) but it's not granular enough to track deletions-- only access.

Comment: Do you know of any 3rd party software for 07 that could do this? Thanks.

Comment: I have no personal experience with any product that claims this functionality. A quick search turns up a NetWrix product (http://www.netwrix.com/mailbox_access_auditing.html) but I have no experience with this product and am not making any kind of recommendation.